# How can I select max value from one column and update another column with selected Max value

Tags: php, sql

```
$query6 = "SELECT MAX(subject_total) AS max FROM results1 WHERE subjects = '{$result_subject}' AND class = '{$student_class}' AND term = '{$result_term}' AND session = '{$result_session}'";

$run_query6 = mysqli_query($connection, $query6);

while($run_query6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query6)) {
    $max = $run_query6['max'];
} 
$sql1 = "UPDATE results1 SET max = ".($max)." WHERE max = ".$max;
$run_query6 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1); }
```

When I run the above code, $sql1 query doesn't update max column. Please help me fix this. I need for the query to update max column with same max value. E.g if 70 is max score in English, it will update all English rows with 70. But its not updating max column.   [image]

Comment: $query6 = " SELECT MAX(subject_total) AS max FROM results1 WHERE `subjects` = '{$result_subject}' AND `class` = '{$student_class}' AND `term` = '{$result_term}' AND `session` = '{$result_session}'";
                $run_query6 = mysqli_query($connection, $query6);
                
while($run_query6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query6)){
                        $max = $run_query6['max'];
}   
      $sql1 = "UPDATE results1 SET max = ".($max)." WHERE max = ".$max;
      $run_query6 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);
}

Comment: This is the code I have,  the post editor refused to accept it

Comment: `WHERE max = ` doesn't seem to make much sense. Do you actually have a column with that name in the table? And why do you need to put the max value into a specific column, when you can just calculate the max value whenever you need it. Also, if it does exist, it seems to me its current value is unlikely to equal the value the last query has just produced...and if it did, updating it would make the data be exactly the same as it was before. Your situation doesn't really make any sense. What are you actually trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: P.s. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting if you're having troubles putting code into your question

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion. How can I output max value for each subject

Comment: I was more questioning why you're trying to put the value back into the table when you've just selected it. It's usually unnecessary to store something you can derive. If you want to show it to the user, output the results of the select query. But are you also saying the query doesn't produce the results you want anyway? It's even more unclear to me now, but perhaps the answer below is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(subject_total) over (partition by subject) as subject_max
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need one query to do the whole job:

```
UPDATE 
    subjects 
join 
    (SELECT subject, max(subject_total) as subject_max from subjects group by subject) m        
    on (subjects.subject = m.subject) 
set 
    subjects.subject_max = m.subject_max;
```

The subquery selects the maximum value for each subject by using the GROUP BY clause.

The JOIN links the subquery to the main table on the `subject` column so that the `SET` can populate the values.

Output:

```
# id, user,  subject, subject_total, subject_max
1,    sam,   English, 50,            51
2,    abi,   English, 51,            51
3,    sam,   agric,   52,            53
4,    abi,   agric,   53,            53
5,    sam,   ICT,     54,            55
6,    abi,   ICT,     55,            55
7,    sam,   French,  56,            58
8,    abi,   French,  57,            58
9,    candy, French,  58,            58
```

Be careful with `max` as a column name - I think it's a MySQL reserved word. My example uses `subject_max` instead

Comment: This query should work, but am having issue integrating it into my project

Comment: @victor I created the query from the sample data you posted. If your schema is different then post that and I'll update the query to match